# why wont the output in terminal line up side by side

Tags: c, arrays, terminal, printf

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int rows;
int col;
int chars;
int callLetter;
int characters;
int counter;


char userinput[100];

char alfabetlow[26][7][5] = {{"     ","     "," *** ","    *"," ****","*   *"," *** "},//lower case a

                         {"*    ","*    ","*    ","**** ","*   *","*   *"," *** "},//lower case b 

                         {"     ","     "," *** ","*   *","*    ","*   *"," *** "},//lower case c

                         {"    *","    *","    *"," ****","*   *","*   *"," *** "},//lower case d

                         {"     ","     "," *** ","*   *","*****","*    "," *** "},//lower case e

                         {"*    ","*    ","*    ","**** ","*   *","*   *"," *** "},//lower case f

                         {"*    ","*    ","*    ","**** ","*   *","*   *"," *** "},//lower case g

                         {"*    ","*    ","*    ","**** ","*   *","*   *"," *** "},//lower case h

                         {"*    ","*    ","*    ","**** ","*   *","*   *"," *** "},//lower case i

                         {"*    ","*    ","*    ","**** ","*   *","*   *"," *** "},//lower case j

                         {"*    ","*    ","*    ","**** ","*   *","*   *"," *** "},//lower case k

                         {"*    ","*    ","*    ","**** ","*   *","*   *"," *** "},//lower case l

                         {"*    ","*    ","**** ","* * *","* * *","* * *","* * *"},//lower case m

                         {"     ","     ","**** ","*   *","*   *","*   *","*   *"},//lower case n

                         {"     ","     "," *** ","*   *","*   *","*   *"," *** "},//lower case o

                         {"     ","     ","**** ","*   *","**** ","*    ","*    "},//lower case q

                         {"     ","     "," ****","*   *"," ****","    *","    *"},//lower case q

                         {"     ","     ","* ** ","*   *","*    ","*    ","*    "},//lower case r

                         {"     ","     "," *** ","*    "," *** ","    *"," *** "},//lower case s

                         {" *   "," *   ","*****"," *   "," *   "," *  *","  ** "},//lower case t

                         {"     ","     ","*   *","*   *","*   *","*   *"," ****"},//lower case u

                         {"     ","     ","*   *","*   *"," * * "," * * ","  *  "},//lower case v

                         {"     ","     ","*   *","*   *","* * *","* * *"," * * "},//lower case w

                         {"     ","     ","*   *"," * * ","  *  "," * * ","*   *"},//lower case x

                         {"     ","     ","*   *"," * * ","  *  "," *   ","*    "},//lower case y

                         {"     ","     ","*****","   * ","  *  "," *   ","*****"},//lower case z
                      };
```

/*"   *               *         **        *                        **                                              *
      *               *        *  *       *                         *                                              *
 ***  *      ***      *  ***   *     **** *       *     *   *  *    *   ****  ****   ***  ****   **** * **   ***  ***** *   * *   * *   * *   * *   * *****

    * ****  *   *  **** *   * ***** *   * ****              * *     *   * * * *   * *   * *   * *   * *   * *      *    *   * *   * *   *  * *   * *     *

 **** *   * *     *   * *****  *     **** *   *   *     *   **      *   * * * *   * *   * ****   **** *      ***   *    *   *  * *  * * *   *     *     *
*   * *   * *   * *   * *      *        * *   *   *     *   **      *   * * * *   * *   * *         * *         *  *  * *   *  * *  * * *  * *   *     *
 *****               ***     ***  *   *  ***  **    *  *   ***  * * * *   *  ***  *       **  *      ***    **   ****   *    * *  * * * *     ***** 
*/

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

while(characters != EOF && characters != '\n'){
    characters = getchar();
    userinput[counter] = characters;
    counter++;
    }


for(col = 0; col <= 25; col++){


for(rows = 0; rows <= 6; rows++){
        printf("%c", alfabetlow[rows][col][chars]);
    }   
}


/*//prints down over
for(col = 0; col <= 6; col++){
    for(row = 0; row <= 25; row++){
        for(chars = 0; chars <= 4; chars++){
            printf("%c", alfabetlow[row][col][chars] );
            }
        printf("");
    }
    printf(" ");

}*/

return 0;
}
```

**why when i run in terminal will my code not write the alphabet side by side instead it rights down over**

Comment: Are you using any `tab`s in your code or just spaces? What is the font in your terminal?

Comment: I use tabs and it is going to be printed in stars in terminal, I am trying to create a program that will print out anything that is input into the terminal in stars

Comment: Damn, i made a similar pogram to spam those "press ctrl + f to see the message" on youtube, but in c++...

Comment: Tabs might have a different width in your editor and your terminal. And by font I mean the *font* your terminal is using to print the stars.

Comment: You need to print a `newline` after each row of stars.

Comment: within my printf i have used spaces not tabs sorry if that is what you mean

Comment: I have tried using /n in print that doesn't work the objective is to be able to input something such as "hey world" and it be printed in terminal as ****

Comment: @dominicbaker In the main part of the code `printf("%c", alfabetlow[rows][col][chars]);` the variable '**chars**' is not initialised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing newline after every printed row. Here's how it should look like:

```
for(int col = 0; col <= 6; col++)
{
  for(int row = 0; row <= 25; row++)
  {
    for(int chars = 0; chars <= 4; chars++)
    {
      printf("%c", alfabetlow[row][col][chars] );
    }
    printf(" "); // You may also add a space between characters.
  }
  printf("\n"); // New line after each row
}
```

Comment: you life saver!

Answer (score 1):

problem was in:
1. position of the indexing variables.
2. not using a '\n' after printing stars of a line.

this migt be helpful

```
chars =0; // 0=a, 1=b, 2=c, ..... 25=z

for(col = 0; col <= 6; col++){

for(rows = 0; rows <= 4; rows++){

    printf("%c", alfabetlow[chars][col][rows]);
    }
    printf("\n");

}
```